# For Loop on RadioField not working Flask Python

Tags: python, html, flask

Here is my main.py file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, SelectField, RadioField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, URL

questions = ["1+1=2", "2+2=4", "3+3=7"]

correct = [1, 1, 0]


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '8BYkEfBA6O6donzWlSihBXox7C0sKR6b'
Bootstrap(app)


class Answers(FlaskForm):

choices = RadioField('Label', coerce=int, choices=[(1, 'True'), (0, 'False')], validators= 
[DataRequired()])


class Submit(FlaskForm):

  done = SubmitField('Submit')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def answer():
form = Answers()
submit = Submit()
print(form.validate_on_submit())

if request.method == "POST":
    print(request.form['choices'])
    return redirect(url_for('score'))

return render_template('index.html', questions=questions, correct=correct, form=form, submit=submit)


@app.route('/results')
def score():
return render_template("result.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":

app.run(debug=True)
```

And here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Exam Web-Application</title>
    {% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="static/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="questions">
    {% for x in range(0,3) %}
    <div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Question {{ x + 1}}:</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div>
                    <p> {{ questions[x] }} </p>

                     {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
         {{ wtf.quick_form(submit,  button_map={"done": "primary"}) }}



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So in the POST method, I want to get and print all the selected values of all RadioField choices but the current code prints an empty list it returns nothing, what am I doing wrong, can we not use loops to make multiple Fields and get the inputted value as a list?

Comment: Have you tried using the form directly? (e.g. `form.choices.data`)?

Comment: I tried form.choices.data it still returns None